# webpage hosted on a server which is pointed by separated domain name, how to hide original server path?

Tags: php, url-rewriting, webserver, hosting

Am sure there's answer on Google but I don't know how to formulate my question:

A php website is hosted on server like this: http://sub.realserver.com/website/index.php
Now I want to link the real domain name to it: http://therealwebsite.com

Problem is, when user visits:http://therealwebsite.com, he will see http://sub.realserver.com/website/index.php as he browse through other pages.

Question is how do I hide this realserver path and replace it with the domain name?

Thanks

edit: the website is hosted on a different server as the real domain name

Comment: Please share with us what web server software you are using. //EDIT: Are the web site and the domain hosted on the same server? That's critical information to answer your question.

Comment: the website is hosted on a different server as the real domain name

Comment: Are you able to host PHP scripts on the server that hosts your domain name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume the domain name and the web site are pointing to the same server.

Although you could use URL rewriting (works with almost all popular web servers), the better solution is to set up your web server to provide that web site for the root of that domain name. How to do that completely depends on what server software you are using.

In apache, you need to create a so-called Virtual Host, configure it to respond to your domain name and set its DocumentRoot directive to the directory where your site is located.

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html for an example.

EDIT: I just read your comment.  I'm afraid your options are rather limited. The easiest solution, but also the most dirty one, is to create one page with an IFRAME on it, that loads the site from the real server. You could also host a PHP proxy and on the server that hosts your domain name, and let it proxy the site on your

http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-proxy/

(I never used this, nor am I affiliated with this project, but it seems to claim to do what you want.)

I highly recommend though that you update your DNS records on your domain name so that it points to your server that hosts your site, and that you add a virtual host there.

Comment: Thank you Pelle ten Cate! You gave me a hint about the Iframe method. I was able to find an option (location / frame) on the domain name and when I choose "frame", it masks the original server path.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with asp, there is a good resource on it here -

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx